# Service Stack Vue SPA + SharpApp

Tags: typescript, vue.js, .net-core, servicestack

We are developing the SharpApp, initially, I started with parcel-webapp template using the following article.

https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/parcel-webapp

Now, we are trying to use the Vue framework into that project. I saw the service stack website, they have a project template vue-spa which is a standalone project template.

https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-new

I need to integrate parcel-webapp into vue-spa template. Any idea how can we do that?

Regards,
Jamil

Comment: FYI, the reason we use the SharpApp (parcel-webapp) so that we can write the #script and also compile & deploy the app as a chromium desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely you'll be able to use the full Vue SPA npm toolchain that the [vue-spa Project Template](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-spa) uses.

The easiest options is either to use [Parcel's built-in Vue support](https://parceljs.org/vue.html) or adopt the npm-free approach that the [vue-lite Project Template](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-lite) by using a local copy of all the [pre-compiled vue libraries](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-lite/tree/master/wwwroot/lib) in your App.

The vue-lite template uses a [server bundled solution](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-lite/blob/60c1a7941fa0f487ad51dd838fbffe59c1c8bb68/wwwroot/_layout.html#L35-L64) which uses the optimal unminified sources whilst debugging and the [minified bundled sources in Production](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-lite#bundling).

Comment: can I keep my SharpApp and add Vue support to it? All I need is to use the vue framework in the SharpApp?

Comment: @Jamil That's what both options talk about, it's a Parcel app so you should be able to use its built-in Vue support (haven't tested it myself) otherwise you can use the same approach as the vue-lite projects and reference the pre-compiled static js libraries, which doesn't require webpack/npm.

Comment: As per this article
https://parceljs.org/vue.html
It's out of the box supported into the Parcel. Is that true and I can just write the Vue code into my existing SharpApp?

Comment: @Jamil try it, I haven't tested it myself.  Try it and see what works, if it doesn't try including static js libraries.

Comment: are you planning to build the vs template for the sharpapp, like we have for Vue and Other frameworks?

Comment: @Jamil No VS Templates only contain .NET Framework project templates, [Sharp Apps](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps) are .NET Core only Apps, which don't have any build/toolchain of normal .NET Apps, you just run the `app` or `x` tool and develop while it's running.